# slide numbering in Beamer class (Warsaw theme)

Tags: beamer

I'm using the beamer class and Warsaw theme. Is there any way to have slide numbering at the bottom of the page and on the left (as 2/10) in this theme?
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}‎
‎‎‎‎‎\usetheme{Warsaw‎}‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎‎\title{How to number the ...?‎} 
‎‎\author{My name‎} 
‎‎\date{06‎.06.2005} 
‎\begin{frame}‎
‎\titlepage‎
‎‎‎\end{frame}‎‎‎
‎‎\section{Intro‎}‎
‎\begin{frame}‎
‎‎\frametitle{There are many ...‎}‎ 
‎‎\end{frame}‎‎
‎\end{document}‎
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to select an outer theme. `\useoutertheme{infolines}` should give you the desired format.

If you just want to include the numbers, you have to adopt the original code for the `footline` from the outer theme `shadow` which in turn uses the the format from the `split` theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{How to number the ...?}
\author{My name}
\date{06‎.06.2005}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\hfill\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\section{Intro‎}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{There are many ...}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that by moving the `\title` etc into the preamble, this will also be used for the PDF metadata.

Comment: Do I put this command after \usetheme{Warsaw‎}‎‎?

Comment: Yes. But it does change more than just the numbers in the footer.

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do if I don't want to have the  the institution name or the current date?

Comment: In that case you need to design the `footline` element manually, using the code from the Warsaw theme, see edit above.

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks man.

Comment: many thanks...awesome stuff, im looking for this only

Comment: Thanx!!
I was looking exactly for this. It leaves everithing in its right place plus adding the desired frame numbering.

Answer (score 11):

If placing the frame numbers on the right hand site is sufficient, this can now easily be done with  by using `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]` after the theme.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title{How to number the ...?‎}
\author{My name}
\date{06‎.06.2005}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{There are many ...‎}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(this requires beamer version >= 3.50)

Comment: Neat. And if you don't want to display the total number of slides, use `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]
` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Just stumpled upon this while googling.

A slightly more forward approach to simply add page numbers to the old macro would be

```
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
   \oldmacro\hfill%
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

as seen on the texblog ( http://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/beamer-footline-frame-number/ ).

Just add it to the preamble.
Works with  "Warsaw", "Copenhagen", "Malmoe" and "Luebeck.

Comment: Works for "Berlin" as well!

Comment: .. .. however, it shows counting on/from title page.