# Frame numbering in Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

> This is a follow-up question to [slide numbering in Beamer class (Warsaw theme)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/slide-numbering-in-beamer-class-warsaw-theme)

In fact, I was trying to put frame numbering in my presentation using Warsaw theme. All I wanted is to put the numbering on bottom right corner. Therefore, I modified the option given by @CarstenThiel in the above link as

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
```

Similarly, @MikeR's answer at [Beamer: Hide Backup Slides from Navigation Panel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21247/beamer-hide-backup-slides-from-navigation-panel) works the same:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\insertshorttitle\expandafter{%
    \insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

**My question here is that, is it possible for me to have a different color in the frame numbering area as shown below?**[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add another `beamercolorbox` to the `footline` template and add the information about the frame numbers there, using the desired color; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{mycolor}{fg=red,bg=olive}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{mycolor}%
\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the footline:

[image]