# Removing frame number from title page (Warsaw theme)

Tags: beamer

I am working with Warsaw theme. I found a code in order to add frame numbering by "googling". As a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer} 

\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\hfill\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title{Linearized Model}
\subtitle{Results from Numerical Implementation}
\author[DA, GC]{\underline{First Author}, Second Author} 
\date{\today} 

\AtBeginSection[]  
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Presentation Outline} 
\tableofcontents[currentsection] 
\end{frame}
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Overview of VENU Model}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivations for the Modeling\ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Original work; 2012}
\begin{itemize}
\pause \item BlaBla
\pause \item BlaBla
\pause \item BlaBla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Frame numbering appears as desired. 
Questions:
1) What should I add in the preamble in order to avoid frame numbering of the title page (first page). The numbering should continue with 2 in the Presentation Outline.

2) What should I do if I want the numbering to starts from the Presentation Outline (that is, the title page is not counted at all in the total number of pages).

3) How I should modify above code in order to move the numbering in the right corner instead of the left one;

Adding 
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

results in starting the numbering from 0 but still is not what I want.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Actually I found the code here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/slide-numbering-in-beamer-class-warsaw-theme

Comment: Hi. The first answer (the accepted one) seems to work with the Madrid theme, not the Warsaw. And the other  workaround with adding  `[plain]`  modifies completely the title page.

Comment: As I wrote above the \begin{frame}[plain] \titlepage \end{frame}` modifies completely the title page.

Comment: @dimitries Sorry, I did not read your comment properly

Comment: No problem. In fact, the proposed workaround disappears completely the footer graphics.

Comment: I deleted my comments about the possible duplicate since they are clearly misleading as you want to keep the footer on the title page.

Comment: Ok. LaTeX and Beamer are both great but sometimes you have to search quite a lot for this superfially simple...Fortunately there is this forum:-)!

Comment: I found another workaround that seems to work in my minimal example here http://mnwrhsn.blogspot.fr/2011/05/give-slide-number-in-warsaw-theme-of.html It is rather simple, but it does not work in the actual presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What should I add in the preamble in order to avoid frame numbering of the title page (first page). The numbering should continue with 2 in the Presentation Outline.

If you use

```
 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage 
 \end{frame}
```

the number of the Outline is 2. In order to no print the frame numbers on the title frame, use either the `[plain]` option, which removes the footer or redefine the footer for the title page.

> 2) What should I do if I want the numbering to starts from the Presentation Outline (that is, the title page is not counted at all in the total number of pages).

This is exactly what the

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

you mentioned in your question, does.

> 3) How I should modify above code in order to move the numbering in the right corner instead of the left one;

move the `\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber` to the other side of the footer

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer} 

\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title{Linearized Model}
\subtitle{Results from Numerical Implementation}
\author[DA, GC]{\underline{First Author}, Second Author} 
\date{\today} 

\AtBeginSection[]  
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Presentation Outline} 
\tableofcontents[currentsection] 
\end{frame}
} 

\begin{document}

{

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }


\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}


}

\section{Overview of VENU Model}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivations for the Modeling\ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Original work; 2012}
\begin{itemize}
\pause \item BlaBla
\pause \item BlaBla
\pause \item BlaBla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a separate footline for the title page, after title page subtract `1` from `framenumber`:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{shadow theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \mbox{}\hfill\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle \hfill \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title{Linearized Model}
\subtitle{Results from Numerical Implementation}
\author[DA, GC]{\underline{First Author}, Second Author}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Presentation Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
{\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fil,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\mbox{}\hfill\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}    %% add this here

\section{Overview of VENU Model}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Motivations for the Modeling\ldots}
\begin{itemize}
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\item BlaBla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Original work; 2012}
\begin{itemize}
\pause \item BlaBla
\pause \item BlaBla
\pause \item BlaBla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer. It works as desired. Unfortunately I could not vote for both answers.